# MySQL Cluster Data/SQL Node Connects Under ndbd But Not Under mysqld

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

In a MySQL cluster I have three hosts, one with a manager node, and the other two are each both a data node and sql node. Connecting to the manager is possible, however only as [ndbd] and not [mysqld]... Meaning the manager sees them as data nodes but not as sql nodes. Everything looks as it should other than the "not connected" part, and I receive no error messages. So my question is why is the manager node only recognizing each machine as a data node and not as mysql node as well?

Below you can see the ndb_mgm cluster configuration followed by the contents of config.ini:

```
    Cluster Configuration
    ---------------------
    [ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
    id=2     @10.0.40.105    (mysql-5.5.25 ndb-7.2.7, Nodegroup: 0, Master)
    id=3     @10.0.40.100    (mysql-5.5.25 ndb-7.2.7, Nodegroup: 0)

    [ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
    id=1     @10.0.40.119    (mysql-5.5.25 ndb-7.2.7)

    [mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
    id=4 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)
    id=5 (not connected, accepting connect from any host)
```

config.ini:

```
    [ndbd default]
    # Options affecting ndbd processes on all data nodes:
    NoOfReplicas=2    # Number of replicas

    [tcp default]
    # TCP/IP options:

    [ndb_mgmd]
    # Management process options:
    hostname=10.0.40.119          # Hostname or IP address of MGM node
    datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster  # Directory for MGM node log files
    NodeId=1

    [ndbd]
    # Options for data node-1:
                                    # (one [ndbd] section per data node)
    hostname=10.0.40.105            # Hostname or IP address
    datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files
    NodeId=2

    [ndbd]
    # Options for data node-2:
    hostname=10.0.40.100           # Hostname or IP address
    datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files
    NodeId=3

    #one [mysqld] per storage node
    [mysqld]
    [mysqld]
```

/etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=10.0.40.119

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=10.0.40.119
```

I have some confusion about starting mysqld. The process I go through to start each node is as follows:

ndb_mgmd:

```
ndb_mgmd --initial --skip-config-cache -f /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini

ndb_mgm
```

ndbd/mysqld:

```
ndbd --initial

/etc/init.d/mysql.server start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown your `my.cnf` file for your `mysqlds` but my guess is that you're missing one of the following 2 lines from its `[mysqld]` section:

```
ndbcluster

ndb-connectstring=10.0.40.119:1186
```

OK - so you've defined those parameters in your `my.cnf` file.

Next thing to check - are you using the `mysqld` that came with MySQL Cluster (i.e. not a 'regular' `mysqld` - which isn't supported)?

Try starting the `mysqld` with the `--verbose` option and see if there are more clues. Take a look at the Cluster log (should be on **10.0.40.119** in the **/var/lib/mysql-cluster** folder. Take a look any log entries generated by the `mysqld`.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. I have added the my.cnf configuration to my post.

Comment: Hi I have edited my post in response to your advice. Is the way I am doing it wrong?  How do I start the mysqld specific to mysql cluster?

Comment: When I attempt to start mysqld --verbose it says the following "InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11 InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files."

Comment: Also cleaning files might help http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/setting-up-mysql-cluster-on-two-systems